# DisplayFormat attribute's DataFormatString parameter does not work when used with @Html.TextBoxFor()

Tags: datetime, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations, string-formatting, html-helper

I have a model with some date and time properties.

The time properties have the following DataAnnotation:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm tt}")]
```

And the date properties have:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
```

However these are only respected when I use `@Html.EditorFor()` and not `@Html.TextBoxFor()`.

My current situation will not allow me to use the `EditorFor`, so how can I force the `TextBoxFor` to respect these format strings?

Comment: why do you have to use `TextBoxFor` ?

Comment: validation might be related to your `CultureInfo` that you are using in your app.

Comment: like i mentioned it might be due to language and datetime setting of your environemtn

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDate, "{0:d MMM yyyy}")
```

There's also an overload that takes html attributes, so you can set the CSS class, wire up datepickers, etc:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDate, "{0:d MMM yyyy}", new { @class="input-large" })
```

Comment: just saying that you can apply your styles. such as jquery date picker

Comment: I am using MVC 5, having same problem but the above solution is not working. `        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
        </div>`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an extension method could be created:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString DateTimeFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        var compilationResult = expression.Compile();
        TValue dateValue = compilationResult((TModel)html.ViewDataContainer.ViewData.Model);
        var body = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
        return html.TextBox(body.Member.Name, (Convert.ToDateTime(dateValue)).ToCustomDateFormat(), new { id = body.Member.Name, datepicker = true });
    }
```

the method ToCustomDateFormat could be an extension method for dateTime types which returns string value in desired format.

Usage:

```
@Html.DateTimeFor(x=>x.AnyDateTimeProperty)
```

This way, the formatting of all datetime variable can be controlled from a single function. Worked fine for me (for `DateTime` and `DateTime?` properties), although I am not sure if compiling the expression on run-time is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

An option I have done for this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Patient.DOB, new { @Value = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", Model.EndDate)  })
```

Answer (score 0):

In MVC5 you can call the display format defined in your view avoiding to duplicate the datetime format, just code it the following way:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TotalAmount, Model.DOB.GetDateTimeFormats()[0])
```